# Regex to match this pattern (numbers must be between brackets divided by minus)

Tags: regex

I want to match a pattern with regex, the pattern is:

```
A-Za-z1-9[0-9-0-9]
```

so for example:

> test1[1-50]

Can you help me ?

Solution update:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\[[0-9]+-[0-9]+]$
```

Comment: So you want a regex to match `test` followed by two numbers is that right? The pattern you shared doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I want to match test1[1-50] with the square brackets and the minus char

Comment: Try `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+\[[0-9]+-[0-9]+]`

Comment: ^[A-Za-z0-9]+\[[0-9]+-[0-9]+]$, this one works, thank you

Comment: The `Solution update` should be put as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: [`[A-Za-z]+[1-9]\[[0-9]+-[0-9]+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/ohdZg5/1). You might also want to add `\b` at the start of the regex to match only after non words character.

- `[A-Za-z]+` matches things like `test`, only letters are accepted, one or more times
- `[1-9]` matches a any digit but 0
- `\[[0-9]+-[0-9]+\]` matches one or more digits twice and separated with `-`. All this must be enclosed with square brackets. (You need to escape those with `\` because they are metacharacters)